# %~nF is not Working with batch file

Tags: batch-file

I am running below command directly from command Prompt

```
for /R . %F in (".\*.dtsx") do dtutil /FILE "%F" /DESTServer "myserver" /COPY SQL;MarketsWorkflow\%~nF
```

Then it's running successfully.

But if i save that command in .bat file and execute from command Prompt
then i am getting below error

```
The following usage of the path operator in batch-parameter
substitution is invalid: %~nF


For valid formats type CALL /? or FOR /?
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
```

What' wrong with running command from file.

Please let me know what i am doing incorrect.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: try with `for /R . %%F in (".\*.dtsx") do dtutil /FILE "%F" /DESTServer "myserver" /COPY SQL;MarketsWorkflow\%%~nF` - you need doubled % in batch file.

Comment: You forgot `%F` is only in command line

Answer (score 3):

When using the `FOR` command in a batch file you need to use two percent-symbols for the variable. For example: %%F

Running `FOR /?` from the command-line gives the help topic, which provides this information about using the command in a batch file.

> To use the FOR command in a batch program, specify %%variable instead
>   of %variable.

Microsoft's documentation on [Using batch files](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/batch.mspx) also has information about using the FOR command in a batch file.